# Drawing circles in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes, adorner

I am trying to write a WPF application where you can draw circles on a window by double clicking it. So far I have this code:

```
public class ShapeAdorner : Adorner
{
    private readonly Ellipse _circle;

    public ShapeAdorner(UIElement adornedElement, Point circleCenter)
        : base(adornedElement)
    {
        _circle = new Ellipse
        {
            Width = 10,
            Height = 10,
            Stroke = Brushes.Black,
            StrokeThickness = 1.5
        };
        _circle.Margin =
            new Thickness(left: circleCenter.X, top: circleCenter.Y, right: 0, bottom: 0);
        base.AddVisualChild(_circle);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        _circle.Arrange(new Rect(finalSize));
        return finalSize;
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        _circle.Measure(constraint);
        return constraint;
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        return _circle;
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }
}
```

Here's the client code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        AdornerLayer adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(myLabel);
        adornerLayer.Add(new ShapeAdorner(adornedElement: myLabel, circleCenter: e.GetPosition(myLabel)));
    } 
}
```

The circles are supposed to be centered at the point where you double click the window; however, the circles drawn by the code above are centered below and to the right of "the double click point". How can this be fixed?

EDIT: `myLabel` has `Height=350` and `Width=525`. Let's say that I double click the point `(X,Y)`; then the circle gets plotted at `((350+X)/2,(525+Y)/2)`.

EDIT 2: Just for completeness, here's the .xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="Adorners.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Adorners project" Height="350" Width="525" MouseDoubleClick="Window_MouseDoubleClick">
    <Grid>
        <Label Name="myLabel" Content="my label" Background="Red"></Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: is it really too far to the left? if you're not compensating for the circle dimensions, it should be to far to the right. if it really is to far to the right, you should use subtraction on both dimensions, otherwise use my awnser

Comment: My mistake - I've corrected it to "right".

Comment: Thanks to Kent Boogaart, H.B., and aL3891 for answering. However, I don't think you have quite "nailed it". The circles are not offset by a constant; see the "EDIT" part of my question for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answers are correct. However, the main problem was that I had omitted these two lines:

`_circle.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

_circle.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;`

The default value `Stretch` caused a huge offset error.

Answer (score 2):

Where you set the margin you have to subtract the radius from the top and left properties to offset the circle.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to offset by half the width/height of the circle. Hard-coded here to make it easy to follow:

```
AdornerLayer adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(myLabel);
var point = e.GetPosition(myLabel);
point.X -= 5;
point.Y -= 5;
adornerLayer.Add(new ShapeAdorner(myLabel, point));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the witdth and height into conserderation when you're setting the margin. the top should be the centerposition minus half of the height, and the same for the left:

```
new Thickness(
     left: circleCenter.X + (_circle.Width/2), //farther to the right
     top: circleCenter.Y - (_circle.Height/2), //higher up
     right: 0, bottom: 0);
```

Comment: Turns out it was actually to far to the right, not to far to the left. so subtraction should be used on both dimentions as in everyones elses awnser :)